# sendmail can't connect with remote systems

Tags: email, sendmail

When I send email from a local machine, sendmail can't connect to the SMTP server at remote sites, e.g. Google Mail, Yahoo Mail.  My local sendmail can connect to other machines in my domain just fine.

In /var/log/maillog, with sendmail logging set to 15, I see this:

Dec 17 18:14:11 foobar sendmail[32357]: oBH7EBms032355: makeconnection (aspmx.l.google.com. [74.125.53.27]) failed: Connection refused by aspmx.l.google.com.

Dec 17 18:14:11 foobar sendmail[32357]: oBH7EBms032355: makeconnection (aspmx.l.google.com. [74.125.53.27]) failed: Connection refused by aspmx.l.google.com.

Dec 17 18:14:11 foobar sendmail[32357]: oBH7EBms032355: makeconnection (alt1.aspmx.l.google.com. [74.125.65.27]) failed: Connection refused by alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.

and so on.

What bit of configuration am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
telnet aspmx.l.google.com 25
```

and look for an SMTP banner.  If that fails, try

```
telnet www.teaparty.net 25
```

and look for the banner.  That latter is my mail server, and I *know* it's not blocking inbound 25 from anyone.  If those both fail, your ISP is likely blocking outbound port 25 connections.

Comment: Right.  We have a local email relay for outbound mail.  I used that machine as the SMARTHUB setting in sendmail, and now I can send out email.